# Element on element gets clicked both by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a div which has multiple elements nested. If I press on the div, the buttons appear in the same DIV. If I press on the button however, the buttons dissapear as well (this is because of a toggleClass on the div)

I've tried returning but that isn't working as well. See below for a JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/p168uLv2/

```js
$(document).on('click', "[data-link=level1]", function() {
  console.log("li clicked");

  $(this).find(".knoppenbalk").toggleClass("displaynone");

});

$(document).on('click', "[data-link=solo]", function() {
  console.log("solo BUTTON clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-link="level1" class="limodeknop">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="modeknop">
    <div class="titel">
      <lrmodenaam>Level 1</lrmodenaam>
      <lrsubmode>Tutorial</lrsubmode>
    </div>
    <div class="knoppenbalk displaynone">
      <div data-link="solo" class="solo btn">Solo</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is made with jQuery, and I'm working with Framework7, but I don't think thats an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should stop the propagation of the events (calling **bubbling**). You can search tons of articles about it.

http://jsfiddle.net/p168uLv2/1/

```
$(document).on('click',"[data-link=solo]", function(e){
    console.log("solo BUTTON clicked");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This only apply to the child element, to avoid the parent click propagation.

Comment: EDIT: Not working... Is it possible that Framework7 is the fault here?

Comment: I will ask aanother question with the proper labels

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why don't works. This is the correct way to make this. Maybe your framework causes conflicts

Comment: Yeah no problem. Your solution works perfectly if I load jQuery as well. I've asked another question with the proper labels (framework7 instead of jQuery), so I marked your answer as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can stop an event propagating to parent elements with use of:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

You will want to accept `event` as an argument to your inline functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click',"[data-link=solo]", function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log("solo BUTTON clicked");
})
```

;

Comment: An explanation will be fine ;)